# Why does this not set hashtag[] to /#(\w+)/g

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, meteor

I am trying to set the array hashtags to the hashtags in the string posttext, but it doesn't work. Here is the code.

postsubmit.js

```
 var posttext=$(e.target).find('[name=posttext]').val();
 var hashtag=posttext.match(/#\w+/g);

var post = {
  title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
  posttext:posttext,
  hashtag:hashtag
}
```

post.js collection

```
var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, 'title', 'posttext','hashtag'), {
  userId: user._id, 
  username: user.username, 
  submitted: new Date().getTime(),
  commentsCount: 0,
  upvoters: [], votes: 0,
  hashtag:[]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your syntax.

If you want to capture the hashtags from a post content, use the following :

```
var posttext=$(e.target).find('[name=posttext]').val();
var hashtag=posttext.match(/#\w+/g);

var post = {
  title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
  posttext:posttext,
  hashtag:hashtag
}
```

You can test it in your browser console :

```
"Hello everybody, just published my first #meteorjs package ! #javascript".match(/#\w+/g)
> ["#meteorjs","#javascript"]
```

EDIT : need to change the insert code accordingly.

```
var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, ['title', 'posttext', 'hashtag']), {
  userId: user._id, 
  username: user.username, 
  submitted: new Date().getTime(),
  commentsCount: 0,
  upvoters: [],
  votes: 0
});
```

Comment: That makes post submitting get stuck on the submit page.

Comment: The way you reference `posttext` while initializing `hastag` is problematic, you can't reference an object property in another property like this, you have to do this stuff before creating the object. Also, you will have to `_.pick` the `hashtag` property if you want it to be included in your collection. (EDITED my answer btw)

Comment: It is submitting but nothing is going into the hashtag array.

Comment: This is because your insert code is `_.extend`ing the post with an empty hashtag array, in case it would be unset, so you need to `_.pick` the property along with `title` and `posttext`. Got it ?

Comment: so that would look something like this? `var hashtag=posttext.match(/#\w+/g).pick();`

Comment: Updated my answer, does it make sense now ?

Comment: That makes more sense but I still don't have a clue how to make it actually work. with picking it `hashtag=[]` is still empty after submitting a new post with a hashtag in it.

Comment: Ok my bad, `_.extend`ing will actually override the picked value anyway... you can remove it (the `hashtag:[]` part) because it will be initialized with an empty array if no hashtags found.

Comment: See my updated answer, and edit your question with the current code you have.